# Does a process that creates a pair of photons have the same polarization and also the same output of a hidden variable if it existed?

Tags: polarization, bells-inequality

After watching this video on Bell’s inequality [here](https://youtu.be/qd-tKr0LJTM?si=BkObuL08k_grVuMj), it mentions that if you have a process for pair production, in this case a photon pair where the photons travel in opposite directions, the polarization of each photon will be the same. In the video, he uses this example to eventually show what Bell’s inequality is and how it is violated in experiments ruling out hidden variables that are local.

However, the analysis depends upon two things. First, he says that the polarization of each photon would be the same, and that this has been demonstrated experimentally.

Secondly, he says that if there was a hidden variable that determined whether each photon will go through a particular kind of polarization filter, the determination should be the same for each photon if they were measured at different locations. So for example, suppose that Alice and Bob in different locations had three kinds of polarization filters at different angles. Let’s call these 1,2, and 3.

If there was a hidden variable in one photon in a pair that determined that it will pass through Alice’s polarization filter 1, the other photon in the pair must also pass through Bob’s polarization filter 1. This is because, as he states, the hidden variables in each photon, must be the same.

My question is how do we know this? What if the hidden variable is different in each photon of the same pair? How do we rule this out?

Secondly, what is the evidence that the polarization of each photon is the same in a process like this and that it will remain to be in the same polarization when it is measured with, say, filter 1 for both Alice and Bob?

Without these assumptions, does Bell’s inequality hold?

Comment: The hidden variable has to be generated by the time of the splitting of the photon, and if they are recording different values, then they cannot be the variables that we are interested in, since, as the experiments had already showed, if both Alice and Bob measured the same polarisation, then they will get the same results. Your two questions are actually the same question.

Comment: Why can’t alice and bob have the same polarization but have some variable/ force/mechanism, different in each, that allows one to pass through the same polarization filter but not the other?

Comment: Also, how do we know that it remains to be in the same polarization from the splitting of the photon to the point it is measured?

Comment: 1) how would one ever distinguish a "different variable/force/mechanism" from just having the same variable? 2) The same way we established that polarisation is constant across varying spacetime distances and directions.